# How to get attribute value from attribute name in dart(_EVENTVALIDATION from html attribute in dart)?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-pub

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage. I wanted to get the value present inside the value attribute(from the html element given below)

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="__EVENTVALIDATION" 
       id="__EVENTVALIDATION" 
       value="abcdefghijklmnopq" />
```

I got this value by parsing the html after a get request to the webpage in flutter

```
var document = parse(response.body);
```

and after that

```
var event_element = document.getElementById('_EVENTVALIDATION');
```

**What I want now is the value 'abcdefghijklmnopq' as a string.**

So far I have tried using html package (that didn't work).

After that I used xpath (but that also wasn't a success), I have been brainstorming for 2 days straight.

**any kind of help will be highly appreciated :)**

### Here's a sample of my code

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:html/dom_parsing.dart';



    Future<void> fetchdata() async {
  Uri url1 = Uri.parse('https://www.jhjkfw.com/login');

  http.Response response = await http.get(url1);
  var document = parse(response.body)

  var valueofevent = document.getElementById('_EVENTVALIDATION').getAttribute('value');
print(valueofevent);


}
```

**also my pubspec.yaml**

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.0
  html: ^0.15.0
```

> ***I also tried the following method but it gives me an error:***

```
var valueofevent = document.getElementById('_EVENTVALIDATION').getAttribute('value');
```

> **The error states : The method 'getAttribute' isn't defined for the type 'Element'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getAttribute'**

Answer (score 1):

**I made another approach using the following code:**

```
var valueofevent = document.getElementById('_EVENTVALIDATION').attributes['value'];
```

> this works for me perfectly !

Answer (score -1):

You said you tried and it did not work. But not *what* you tried. This *should* work. If it doesn't, you will need to be more specific about what *exactly* does not work:

```
var value = event_element.getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: i tried this but it gives me :The method 'getAttribute' isn't defined for the type 'Element'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getAttribute'

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please? It should be: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Element/getAttribute.html

Comment: im doing this '''var valueofevent = document.getElementById('_EVENTVALIDATION').getAttribute('value');'''(please let me know if that would be enough or not  i will provide more if you need).

Comment: No, that's not enough, because I have no idea what libraries you use for that functions. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i edited my question with a simple example,anything else..?